# UITableView bounds after rotate

Tags: xcode, uitableview, bounds, autoresizingmask

I have a UITableViwe with autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth. Some of the cells contain a UITextField.

When the device is rotated, the table and the text fields resize correctly to the full width of the device, but when I check the bounds of the cell and the bounds of the text field in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: after the rotation - I get the original bounds as if the device was not rotated.

Is there a way to get the actual bounds after the rotation? I need this information to populate the text field correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth for the text view.